# how two link two docker containers, and how to use the mysql client on a mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I'd like to test [webtrees PHP docker](https://github.com/H2CK/webtrees). They suggest connecting to a mysql docker using `--link mysql:db`, as follows:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webtrees --link mysql:db -v /webtrees/data:/var/www/html/data -v /webtrees/media:/var/www/html/media  -e DISABLE_SSL=TRUE -e PORT=80 --restart always dtjs48jkt/webtrees
```

Their README says:

> The image does not contain a MySQL database. Instead you have to use a separate MySQL instance. For example you could use the
> MySQL Docker Image. Using the --link parameter a direct connection to
> the database in an other container could be established. If you use
> the --link parameter it is sufficient to set as database hostname db
> and port 3306. The database user must have all access rights to
> create the necessary database and tables.

However the webtrees container cannot access the mysql server. How I correctly link these two docker containers?

I tried using the official [mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) as follows:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -e MYSQL_DATABASE=webtrees -e MYSQL_USER=my_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_pwd -d mysql:5.5
```

but then I don't know how to link webtrees docker container with the mysql container.

Also, how can I use the mysql client? the documentation gives this example, but I don't understand what are the correct parameters for netowrk and -h:

```
$ docker run -it --network some-network --rm mysql mysql -hsome-mysql -uexample-user -p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, the `--link` option for `docker run` is deprecated according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/), so I wouldn't recommend using it.

With the amount of configuration required, I'd recommend setting up a `docker-compose.yml` instead. I set up the configuration you require like this:

```yaml
version: '3.0'

services:
  webtrees:
    image: dtjs48jkt/webtrees
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      - DISABLE_SSL=TRUE
      - PORT=80
    volumes:
      - /webtrees/data:/var/www/html/data
      - /webtrees/media:/var/www/html/media
    networks:
      - my-network
  
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.5
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=webtrees
      - MYSQL_USER=my_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_pwd
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
```

To run the containers, use:

```
docker-compose up --detach
```

What this will do is spin up a mysql container and a webtrees container according to the configuration you specified in your question with a `network` called `my-network`.

In the web interface of web trees on http://localhost/ you can make it connect to the mysql container with the following configuration, so it will connect to it through the docker network:

[image]

Since the service name in the `docker-compose.yml` is `mysql`, the required hostname is `mysql`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to have all the containers (mysql DB server, mysql client and application) in the same Docker network. By default they are not. Alternatively, `--link` can be used to link them (as shown in webtrees run example), but it's considred as legacy feature and network should be used instead of that.
So what you need to do:

1. Create custom Docker network:
   `docker network create user-network`
2. Run mysql server in that network. Name should be `db`, because webtrees relies on that hostname for DB:
   `docker run --name db --network user-network -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -e MYSQL_DATABASE=webtrees -e MYSQL_USER=my_user -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_pwd -d mysql:5.5`
3. Run mysql client in the same network:
   `docker run -it --network user-network --rm mysql mysql -hdb -umy_user -p`
4. Finally you can run an app in the same network:
   `docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webtrees --network user-network -v /webtrees/data:/var/www/html/data -v /webtrees/media:/var/www/html/media  -e DISABLE_SSL=TRUE -e PORT=80 --restart always dtjs48jkt/webtrees`

After that web app should be accessible from your browser under http://localhost/